# highcharts treemap heatmap level2 color turning black

Tags: highcharts, heatmap, treemap

Hi I have a problem with Highchart Heatmap. when entering level 2, colors turn black and all parts are the same. and this happens when i change the color value to a larger number like 90.
here is the [jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vvz5azbg/) 
in this link click A1 and see problem

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    colorAxis: {
      minColor: ' #d03b53',
      maxColor: '#23c874'
    },
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      formatter: function() {
        return this.point.name + ":" + this.point.value;
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: "treemap",
      levels: [{
        level: 1,
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        borderRadius: 50,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 0
      }, {
        level: 2,
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        borderRadius: 50,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 0
      }],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          color: 'blue',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          HcTextStroke: '3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'
        }
      },
      allowDrillToNode: true,
      data: [{
        id: "id_1",
        name: 'A',
        value: 90,
        colorValue: 90
      }, {
        id: "id_2",
        name: 'A1',
        value: 80,
        parent: 'id_1',
        colorValue: 80
      }, {
        id: "id_3",
        name: 'A2',
        value: 4,
        parent: 'id_1',
        colorValue: 4
      }, {
        id: "id_4",
        name: 'A3',
        value: 6,
        parent: 'id_1',
        colorValue: 6
      }, {
        id: "id_b1",
        name: 'B',
        value: 91,
        colorValue: 91
      }, {
        id: 'id_b2',
        name: 'B1',
        value: 91,
        parent: 'id_b1',
        colorValue: 91
      }, {
        name: 'C',
        value: 4,
        colorValue: 4
      }, {
        name: 'D',
        value: 1,
        colorValue: 1
      }, {
        name: 'E',
        value: 2,
        colorValue: 2
      }, {
        name: 'F',
        value: 2,
        colorValue: 2
      }, {
        name: 'G',
        value: 7,
        colorValue: 7
      }]
    }],
    title: {
      text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like possibly bug, so I have reported it on our [github](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3995)

Comment: Did this get patched? because I don't see the problem..:/

Answer (score 2):

As you might have seen, the GitHub issue has been fixed and closed.
Use a version of Treemap from 4.1.6 or above, and you should not have this problem.

Alternatively it is possible to add the following code snippet after loading Highcharts and before creating the chart:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype.getExtremesFromAll = true;
```